# even after adding use Class i get FatalErrorException in Model.php line 876: Class 'Matiere' not found

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

2 my application show the teacher**(profs)** and if i click on a prof it shows me **the subjects that he teach (matiere)**. so i have  ***Model Profs:***

```
<?php
    namespace App;
    use App\Matiere;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


    class Prof extends Model
    {
      protected $fillable=array('nom','prenom','age','mail');

    public function matieres(){

        return $this->hasMany('Matiere');
    }
    }
```

Now when i click on a specifique teacher i call ***show methode*** :

```
     public function show(Prof $prof)
        {
            return view('Prof.show',compact('prof'));
        }
```

then in ***show.blade.php*** i try to show teacher s subjects

```
 {!! $matiere=$prof->matieres !!}
                    <table class="table">
                       <thead><th>id</th><th>Nom matiere</th></thead>
                       @foreach ($matiere as $mat)
                             <tr> 
                                <td>{{$mat->id}}</td><td>{{$mat->Nom}}</td>
                            </tr>
                       @endforeach
                      </table>
```

the Message error that i get is ***FatalErrorException in Model.php line 876:
Class 'Matiere' not found***

i try to fix the problem by adding use Matiere ;
but it idn t work

how could i fix the problem ? thnks

Comment: Can you show your Matiere class?

Comment: And the code from  line 876 in Model.php

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions That's just where hasMany is defined in the Laravel Eloquent Model.

Comment: `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Prof;

class Matiere extends Model
{

 protected $fillable=array('Nom');

     public function matieres(){
     return $this->BelongsToMany('Etudiant' ,'classes' ,'id_matiere','id_etd' );
    }

    public function profs(){
     return $this->BelongsTo('Prof');
    }
} `

Comment: Try `composer dumpautoload` and see if that helps.

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: Matiere.php contain
`

 public function profs(){
     
return $this->BelongsTo('Prof');

    }`

Answer (score 0):

i fix the problem by changing 2 Models

Prof :

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\Matiere;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Prof extends Model
{
  protected $fillable=array('nom','prenom','age','mail');

public function matieres(){

    return $this->hasMany(Matiere::class,'id_prof'); //Correction
}
}
```

And Matier :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Prof;

class Matiere extends Model
{

    protected $fillable=array('Nom');

    public function profs(){
        return $this->BelongsTo(Prof::class,'id_prof'); //Correction
    }
}
```